# Bootstrapping a NW.js / Electron application

Tags: electron, nw.js

I am building a HTML/JS/CSS application that I would like to distribute packaged either as a NW.js or Electron app. I am new to both, and have read that the packaged executables can be quite large. Since the application would be free, I find that the cost of distributing it from a CDN to be too high.

I was wondering if there was any installer that allowed the "standard" parts of the executable (the Chrome components, etc.) to be downloaded as a shared library from a free CDN, as part of the app's installation / first execution?

Answer (score 1):

With either one, you could host the packages on Github using the "releases" feature, which is free. This is a common approach for a lot of open source Electron applications.

Here are some examples of this being done:

- [yoda](https://github.com/whoisandie/yoda/releases/tag/v1.0.0)
- [Caprine](https://github.com/sindresorhus/caprine/releases/tag/v1.3.0)

[Here](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-releases/) is the official documentation on Github releases.

There is a module for Electron designed to make this easy called [electron-gh-releases](https://github.com/jenslind/electron-gh-releases).

Comment: Interesting. My application is free but not open source (at least not yet). Do you know if they allow publishing binaries only?

Comment: With nwjc you can protect the source files without performance loss.